# Building docker firmeware esp32 error:unknown option to `s'

Tags: docker, nodemcu

I'm trying to build nodemcu firmware for esp32 using docker ce.

I'm getting this error message:

```
:~/nodemcu-firmware$ sudo docker run --rm -ti -v `pwd`:/opt/nodemcu-firmware marcelstoer/nodemcu-build build-esp32
sed: -e expression #1, char 99: unknown option to `s'
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Kind regards
Arne

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Maybe you could add more details (by editing your question), e.g. what commands or operations are you doing to build...?

Comment: Isn't this https://github.com/marcelstoer/docker-nodemcu-build/issues/58?

Answer (score 1):

@Marcel Stör: You are right. This code solve my problem:

```
docker run --rm -ti -v `pwd`:/opt/nodemcu-firmware marcelstoer/nodemcu-build bash
git submodule update --init
exit
```